Can a paper be assessed again by the same journal after a retraction?
Can I resubmit my previously retracted paper to the same journal?

Of course you can. But are you asking if there is a chance that the journal will not reject it?

Are you asking whether you can (meaningfully/successfully/…?) submit the exact same paper, or rather a revised version?

This question is meaningless if you don't tell us why the paper was retracted in the first place, and what you did to the paper to make it publishable again.

This might be really stupid, but does the OP mean "rejected" instead of "retracted"?

@Begnnier The commenter is not calling you "really stupid", they're saying that their own comment might be stupid/silly, and they are asking that you confirm that you really mean "retracted".

It rarely makes much sense to ask "Can I ...?" questions of this kind, because the answer is almost always "obviously yes". To resubmit your paper to the same journal, you go to the submission site and, well, submit it!
But you probably actually want to something along the lines of:

Is it unusual to resubmit a previously retracted journal to the same journal?
Do you know of any instances where a journal has republished a revision of a previously retracted journal?
Am I more likely to be successful if I submit my previously retracted paper to the same paper, or to another paper?

My answers to those questions would be:

It is almost certainly unusual.
No, I know of no instance of a previously retracted paper being published in revised form in the original journal (confined to my familiar domains: economics, psychology, medicine)
And yes, I would expect that a new editor (i.e., new journal) will look at your paper with fewer preconceptions that if you were to resubmit it to the same journal.


The chances for success (i.e., publication) will depend very much on the details: was the original paper retracted after publication or during the review process, was it retracted for scientific misconduct or a serious-but-honest error, what has changed in the new version, and so forth.

To add to PDB's answer, such "retraction and republication" in the same journal is possible in principle. Per the COPE Guidelines (emphasis added),

An author may republish some of the work if not all of the content was found to be unreliable. In order to do so transparently, authors should notify the editors of the new journal of the prior retraction and it is likely appropriate to cite the retraction, indicating why the work was flawed and what has been corrected in the new article. Permission to republish also needs to be agreed with the copyright holder of the retracted work.
In some instances, journals may wish to work with authors to concurrently retract an article that was found
to be fundamentally flawed while simultaneously publishing a linked and corrected version of the work.
This strategy of ‘retract and republish’ is not commonly used, but may provide an opportunity for journals
and authors to transparently correct the literature when a simple correction cannot sufficiently address
the flaws of the original article (eg, see Retraction and republication – a new tool for correcting the scientific
record? European Science Editing (https://b.link/ese-1). In this instance, the original article should not
be completely removed or ‘replaced’, but should be retained and linked to.

Note: I've preserved the defunct URL in the quote, but replaced the link with an archived version.
I've mainly heard about this practice in medical journals through reporting by Retraction Watch. Here is an example. Here's also an example where a journal apparently retracted an article due to legal threats, and later republished it with some modifications. Here's a tragicomic example where the journal mistakenly retracted the wrong paper and issued the statement:

This is a retraction of a retraction notice. Due to technical errors at the Editorial office of the journal, a retraction notice[1] was published retracting the article titled, “Sample size estimation and power analysis for clinical research studies[2]. However the actual article which needs to be retracted is titled, “An overview of randomization techniques: An unbiased assessment of outcome in clinical research” by the same author[3]. The correct retraction notice will be subsequently published and the incorrectly retracted article will be republished in the forthcoming issue of the journal.

As for the question of whether you can republish your paper in the same journal that retracted it, well, that really is up to the journal in question. Given that the practice is not commonly used even in fields where it is sometimes employed, I expect few journals will have a developed workflow for such republication, or even a policy allowing it. Among journals that might allow it, I believe editors would primarily be interested if they deem the paper to be important, and deem the issues to be limited to honest errors or to be caused by the journal itself.

"In some instances, journals may wish to work with authors to concurrently retract an article that was found to be fundamentally flawed while simultaneously publishing a linked and corrected version of the work." This does not seem to match the OPs situation.
